# Disable all blackground apps when using some apps (possibly with Tasker)

Tags: applications, tasker, task-management

Is there a way to disable **all** background apps (gmail, google notifications, messaging apps, etc...) when a certain/any app is running? I would like to do this because I play a certain game ([Sine Line](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ThirdState.SineLine&hl=en)) which requires you to press the screen for short periods of time, in a very controlled manner, and any lag kills me.

I assume this could be useful for other resource-intensive apps, such as maps/gps, or image editing.

Either disabling/killing background apps when a certain or any app is running are acceptable solutions. Tasker is also acceptable, however Tasker itself is quite resource-intensive so avoiding it would be best.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try limiting background process in the Developers Options to One process? This might do the job...

Comment: @esQmo That ought to do the job. I can actually set no background apps. If you write your comment as an answer (maybe with a little more details for other people in the future), I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by forcing the system to limite background processes. Open the Settings > Developers Options > Limite background processes and select No background process.

If Developers Options is not enabled (on Android 4.4.2 and above), enable it at Settings > About phone > Tape 7 times on Build number > Go back to Settings, the option should be on.